# Why is Swift's first(where: ) function not providing the expected result?

Tags: ios, swift

Well... people didn't like my question, but I am not at all clear why... my goal was to be terse, and not get into a long description... Any insights into what pissed y'all off would I'm sure be helpful, didn't come here to ruin anyone's day.

```
func createMatchups() {
    print("tiers are \(tiers[0].status)")
    var tier = tiers.first(where:{ _ in status == .ready})
    print("matching up \(tier)")
    tier!.createMatchups()
}
```

I expected this code to set `tier` to the element in `tiers` where `status` is set to `.ready`.

Instead, it produces this output:

```
tiers are ready
matching up nil
App/tournament.swift:113: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

the tier is a class with this definition:

```
class Tier {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var tournament : Tournament?
    var playerCount: Int = 0
    var roundRobins: Array<RoundRobin> = []
    var final: Bool = false
    var status: tierStatus = .ready

…
}
```

and tierStatus looks like:

```
enum tierStatus {
    case ready
    case playing
    case complete
}
```

Can someone explain why I'm not seeming to get the first Tier with status .ready?

Comment: `tiers.first(where:{ tier in tier.status == .ready})`

Comment: You most likely got downvoted because it doesn't seem like you tried to understand the code you were writing.

Comment: maybe, but as I explained in a comment, that's code that Swift provided, when it offered to "fix" the code I had.  It seems to me that the downvotes are about whether it was a reasonable assumption that Swift-provided code would be functional. It's the same thing as expecting someone to question the autocomplete when typing in a function. Perhaps the point is that most people who submit non-working code anywhere in Stackoverflow effectively don't understand the code they're writing sufficiently well to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong shorthand syntax. It must be

```
var tier = tiers.first(where:{ $0.status == .ready})
```

Or even shorter

```
var tier = tiers.first { $0.status == .ready }
```

Comment: ok,... what's there is what was substituted when Swift offered to "fix" my code....